# WalletConnect deeplink in android doesn't route to page in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, wallet-connect

I'm developing flutter application and i want implement wallet connect dapps through the deeplinks.

dapp sites give me this link and when I click it, I redirected to my app but I don't have any path in this URL to specify in my app and `GetX` routing get me to that.

`wc:35f76b10-19b5-4d16-8d2f-ac5d430be5e9@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2F4.bridge.walletconnect.org&key=fc9f29c26cc97ad2c476f2f9ba953709d45db540aa1826cb62d3352d3f80bcaa`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call wallet connect uri directly. You Need to specify wallet schema.

Example:
To open below link in metamask wallet you need to add `metamask://wc?uri=` schema

`wc:35f76b10-19b5-4d16-8d2f-ac5d430be5e9@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2F4.bridge.walletconnect.org&key=fc9f29c26cc97ad2c476f2f9ba953709d45db540aa1826cb62d3352d3f80bcaa`

And to launch it use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) like follow.

```dart
  final uri = Uri.tryParse("metamask://wc?uri=wc:35f76b10-19b5-4d16-8d2f-ac5d430be5e9....");

  if (!await launchUrl(uri)) {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $uri');
  }
```